# Typesetting the same content in every margin

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm creating a class for meeting notes and I'm hoping to put the word 'Notes' and possibly lines for people to write on once the meeting notes have been printed out. How would one get the class to typeset the same thing in every margin? Just to be clear, by 'margin' I mean specifically the box where `marginpar` would typeset.

I'm currently using the memoir class (although I'm open to suggestions if another class provides this functionality) with XeLaTeX.

Picture of roughly what I'm after:
[image: badly drawn picture of what I'm after]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%% Packages I'm using, not needed for this example, but included just in case they'd clash.
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[english]{datetime}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

%% in the real thing there is some redefinition of the title, not included here for simplicity

%% Here something would go to make the notes section.

\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Main text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite clear. Is this a one sided doc, such that the note area would be in the same exact spot on every page? In that case I would just add it using eso-pic package or similar

Comment: Thanks, added MWE to the question. At the moment it's two sided.

Comment: Can still be done via what nils writes plus a odd page test

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is the famous `eso-pic` package, but, as daleif said, without an MWE we can't be more specific.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext,eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtTextUpperLeft{%
\hspace{\textwidth}%
\hspace{\marginparsep}%
Notes
}}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```